# How to fix Caused by: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MBeanServerNotification" on tomcat deployment 8.5.27

Tags: spring-boot, web-deployment, tomcat8

I deployed my project locally on a tomcat 9 server and it worked perfectly but when I tried doing the same in a remote deployment server with tomcat 8.5.27 it throws the following error :

```
    20-Jul-2019 11:26:43.039 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-27] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Stream]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:113)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MBeanServerNotification
            at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerMetricsEventually$aa4da135$1(TomcatMetrics.java:259)
            at java.management/javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:238)
            at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerDelegate.sendNotification(MBeanServerDelegate.java:211)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.sendNotification(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1473)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1867)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:955)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:890)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:320)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.registerComponent(Registry.java:634)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:161)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:61)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6228)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
            ... 11 more

    20-Jul-2019 11:26:43.040 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-27] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/home/webadmin/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.27/webapps/Stream.war]
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Stream]]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

I use java 1.8 and springboot version 2.1.2. Till yesterday the code was deployed and functioned properly on the remote server and only today I am getting this error. On my local system with tomcat 9 it still functions correctly. I have **no other dependencies** that are added to the buildpath in eclipse .

Please tell me the reason for this error and the workaround. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Tomcat Maven+Spring Boot project developed in Eclipse IDE. As app server I used in this case Tomcat 9.0.35.

I got this same error

```
Caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MBeanServerNotification
```

when I deployed this application on the remote host server. The application runs without errors on the local server. The operation system on the both servers is Ubuntu 22.04.

I got rid off this error by following these steps:

1. I restarted Tomcat on the remote server.
2. I undeployed this application on the remote server.
3. I moved its war file to the /opt/tomcat/latest/webapps folder.
4. This worked each time I have tried.

However I got always the above error when skipping steps 1. and 2. I also got that error when I pushed the start button next to this application in the Tomcat manager without following the above steps.

Maybe updating or upgrading Tomcat will make these above steps unnecessary? The other solutions some have mentioned didn't work in this case.